# Salesforce product variant are not shown - only simple products are shown?

Tags: search, commerce-cloud, product-rule

I've have set up a store in Salesforce, where I for now have been listed "simple" products.

These are have been shown shown in the store without any problems, the now occur after having created a Product variant, with a base product.

I am not able to see where Product variants in my store, and I have no idea on why?

I have modified my search to also include the attribute set used for creating the variant - and created them as I have created the others.

But for some reason are these not shown.

Are there any particular setting I need to enable to make sure Product variants are shown when searched for?

Answer (score 0):

I would answer from my SFCC experience, so it should be the same.

Try to open the PDP(product details page) of the variant itself and check what details are missing. If you are redirected to the master, then you might want to make the variant a regular single product, then open PDP and adjust all missing information, then roll-back to a variant of the master.

You have to make sure that all the required fields the product to be online to be populated:

- make sure the master is also online first
- they need to be online (the variants)
- make sure the master product has enough 'in-stock' values for all stores (0 & current one)
- make sure the variants also have their 'in-stock' values for all stores (0 & current one)

If you need them in the search make sure they are also searchable.